# What is the difference between continuity and uniform continuity?

Tags: analysis

Difference between continuity and uniform continuity of a function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity will help you.

Comment: This question will probably get closed unless you have a more specific question or confusion about these two concepts.